# how can i upload file to firebase storage and display the download URL?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-storage

i want the file to be uploaded and the download url to be printed
here is the code iv'e used for that

```
<script>
      var file = document.getElementById('file');
      var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

// Create the file metadata
var metadata = {
  contentType: 'image/jpeg'
};
var uploadTask = storageRef.child('images/' + file.name).put(file, metadata);
uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED, // or 'state_changed'
  function(snapshot) {
    // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
    var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
    console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
    switch (snapshot.state) {
      case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
        console.log('Upload is paused');
        break;
      case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
        console.log('Upload is running');
        break;
    }
  }, function(error) {
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'storage/unauthorized':
      // User doesn't have permission to access the object
      break;

    case 'storage/canceled':
      // User canceled the upload
      break;



    case 'storage/unknown':
      // Unknown error occurred, inspect error.serverResponse
      break;
  }
}, function() {
  // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
  uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
    console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
  });
});

      </script>
```

The file is not uploading the console shows the error as follows
[image]

**please help me with the correction of code that uploads the file and displays the download url**

Comment: Please check the quickstart sample to see how they initialize the `file`: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/storage/index.html

Answer (score 0):

the form element responsible for file upload needs to look like this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload/file" method="post">
```